# how to add cache control headers to image served by spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement a binary content controller in Spring MVC.

It's working okay but I want to add caching control headers to the response.

I checked this related question: [Unable to cache images served by Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821518/unable-to-cache-images-served-by-spring-mvc)

But it's using a different method. I wanted to use this requestMapping - produces annotation. Here's what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to set the response headers with the cache control elements.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/binaries/**", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces={MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE,
 MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody byte[] serveResource(WebRequest webRequest, String uri) throws IOException {
    String path = (String)request.getAttribute( HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE );

    BinaryFile bf = binaryService.findByUri(path.replaceFirst("/binaries", ""));
    if (webRequest.checkNotModified(bf.getLastModifiedDate().toDate().getTime()))
    {
        return null;
    };
    return bf.getResource();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
public @ResponseBody byte[] serveResource(WebRequest webRequest, HttpServletResponse response, String uri) throws IOException {
  response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=0, no-cache");
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ResponseEntity` like this:

```
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> serveResource() {
    //..
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
             .lastModified(lastModified)
             .body(bf);
}
```

Or [serve resources directly with Spring Resource Handling support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources).

Note that [multiple HTTP caching improvements are scheduled for Spring Framework 4.2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11792), now is the time to voice your opinion on this (you can comment/votes for issues).

Comment: thanks I was working with Spring resources but because I'm uploading files through the app, there doesn't seem to be a good way to store them reliably on the file system in a J2ee cluster. Everything I read on Stack Overflow suggests to store them in persistent storage.  The headers are kind of working, but last modified is not working properly in HTTPS, and the max-age doesn't seem to be working with the browser refresh (I'm not sure if it's supposed to or not).

Comment: Oh I put the headers on by configuring the WebContentInterceptor by the way.

Answer (score 2):

So I just reimplemented the resource handling and thought I'd post the answer back to this question.

Basically I used the new ResourceHandling framework, and it was surprisingly easy to implement this.

1. Created a BinaryImage class that's backed by a CLOB in the DB. Implement the `Resource` interface from Spring 4.1+.
2. Then I created a new `ResourceResolver` that looks up the incoming requests against a known path "/images".
3. Then configured it in the WebMVC framework.

Code for 2 & 3 follows (1 is ommitted, it's straightforward to implement the interface):

```
/**
 * The Frontend Binary Controller
 */
@Component
public class BinaryResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver{

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(BinaryResourceResolver.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    BinaryImageService binaryService;

    @Override
    public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
        if (!requestPath.startsWith("/"))
        {
            requestPath = "/" + requestPath;
        }
        Resource bf = binaryService.findByUrl(requestPath);

        return bf;
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

Then the configuration code: is in a config class that extends `WebMVCConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(new String[]{"/resources/", "/products/", "/categories/"})
                .setCachePeriod(30);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations(new String[]{"/assets/"}).setCachePeriod(3600);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/frontend/**").addResourceLocations(new String[]{"/frontend/"}).setCachePeriod(3600);


    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").setCachePeriod(3600).resourceChain(true).addResolver(binaryResourceResolver);
    registry.setOrder(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide last modified header while returning the byte array

```
if (webRequest.checkNotModified(bf.getLastModifiedDate().toDate().getTime()))
{
    return null;
};

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat();
response.addHeader("Last-Modified",    dateFormat.format(bf.getLastModifiedDate().toDate().getTime()));   
return bf.getResource();
```