# Httpcache on springboot

Tags: spring-boot, cache-control

I have springboot application that requests an image from url then display it on browser. I want to cache my response using cache-control header.

I use `ResponseEntity` and already set my header with `eTag`. I already checked response header in my browser and it shows :

```
Cache-Control:"max-age=31536000, public"
Content-Type:"image/jpeg;charset=UTF-8"
Etag:"db577053a18fa88f62293fbf1bd4b1ee"
```

my request also have `If-None-Match` header. But, I always get `200` status instead of `304`.

Here's my code

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getimage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage() throws Exception {
    String url = "www.example.com/image.jpeg";
    String eTag = getEtag(url);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(new MediaType("image", "jpeg"));
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000, public");
    headers.add("ETag", eTag);

    URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
    InputStream is = imageUrl.openStream();
    BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(imBuff, "jpeg", baos);
    byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(image, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

I tried using method described in [Unable to cache images served by Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821518/unable-to-cache-images-served-by-spring-mvc) so my code become :

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getimage", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage() throws Exception {
    String url = "www.example.com/image.jpeg";
    String eTag = getEtag(url);

    URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
    long lastModified = httpCon.getLastModified();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(new MediaType("image", "jpeg"));
    headers.add("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000, public");
    headers.add("ETag", eTag);
    headers.add("Last-Modified", new Date(lastModified).toString());

    if (webRequest.checkNotModified(eTag)) {
        return null;
    }
    InputStream is = imageUrl.openStream();
    BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(imBuff, "jpeg", baos);
    byte[] image = baos.toByteArray();

    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(image, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But now i always get `304` status code even if i change the url. I checked `webRequest.checkIsNotModified(...)` either by `eTag` and `last-modified` and it always return true. Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: This question is already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516853/how-to-add-cache-control-headers-to-image-served-by-spring-mvc

Comment: thanks @NitinArora I already tried using method described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821518/unable-to-cache-images-served-by-spring-mvc but, `webRequest.checkNotModified(...)` always return true, either using `eTag` or `lastModified`. Can you help me here?

Comment: If you your image is always going to be static, then we are you trying to serve it dynamically? Use static resources to serve the images. Here is the reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: Mm.. actually i will using RequestMapping path variable as image source url then do some processing to that image before show it in browser. Does it count as serving static resource? I already read that docs and i think that's not what I want.

Comment: No it does not count as a static resource. Just wanted to understand the use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my code. Instead of using `webRequest.checkNotModified(eTag)` i manually check `last-modified` and `eTag` from my resource (which is from s3) and compare it to `if-modified-since` and `if-none-match` in request header.

Besides, i also move everything related to http caching in a filter.